# Change Suite name in Allure report

Tags: java, jenkins, allure

Good day!
I use the following stack: Jenkins + Java8 + Allure + Selenide + Selenoid
The task is as follows: run your test suite in parallel with different input variables. Among these input parameters, I would like to set the name of the Suite in the Allure report.
Now, when running tests in parallel (via jenkinsfile and key word 'parallel'), the result of Allure reports overwrites each other, and as a result, in Jenkins I see only the latest results for each of the 4 methods being run.
I would like to organize all this in such a way as to avoid rewriting test results. While all this is seen through the change of the name of the Suite.
How to change the name of the test itself I found:

```
Allure.getLifecycle().UpdateTestCase(testResult → testResult.setName (“Creation account in '” + customer + “’ ”))
```

But I still haven't figured out how to change the name of the Suite.
Please help and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Allure report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUEsK.jpg)

Here is example how I see the result and I'd change the name of suites because every run rewrite the result of previous one.